# How to convert Dlib weights into tflite format?

Tags: tensorflow, dlib, tensorflow-lite

I want to convert Dlib weights for Face Detection, Face landmarks and Face recognition that is in .dat format into .tflite format. Tensorflow lite requires input format in tensorflow_saved model/ Frozen graph (.pb) or keras model (.h5) format. Conversion of Dlib .dat to any of these will also work. Can anyone help me out that how to do it and are there  converted files available?

Answer (score 0):

> Tensorflow lite requires input format in tensorflow_saved model/ Frozen graph (.pb) or keras model (.h5) format. Conversion of Dlib .dat to any of these will also work.

I think you're on the right track. You should try to convert Dlib to TensorFlow frozen graph, then convert the TensorFlow frozen graph to TensorFlow Lite format following [the guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/devguide#converting_a_tfgraphdef).

Have you tried this? Did you run into any problem when running `tflite_convert`? If you have further questions, please update the original question with detailed error messages.